# Query for Count on coulmns by condition with Group BY

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Table structure

```
id(int)
dated_on(datetime)
(many_more)
```

Table having thousands of data grouped by id.

```
I want result as id, count of that id, 
also count of id having date difference is week.(i.e. count of data last week)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
id,
count(id) as cnt,
sum(if(now() - interval 7 day <= dated_on,1,0)) as lastweek
from table
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  id,
  COUNT(*),
  SUM(CASE WHEN dated_on = CURDATE() - 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  id
```

Comment: it will give only count of date having difference exactly 7

Comment: @SomnathMuluk - That was intentional, it seemed to be what the OP asked for...`having date difference is week`

Comment: @Dems-k...sorry...I apologise...sometimes i don't remember my question? But I remember my requirement...

Answer (score 0):

I also got solution:

```
SELECT id, count(id) as counter, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF( CURDATE(), dated_on ) < 7 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS latest_count
FROM my_table
GROUP BY id
```